# Why does undefined get added to my string?

Tags: javascript

I am very green when it comes to understanding the basics why things happen in native js. I am curious to know why I get undefined added to my results when I concatenate the following:

```
function myAdd(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

myAdd('hello' + ' ' + 'world');
```

Gives me "hello worldundefined"

When the following will give me more of what I am looking for:

```
function myAddB(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z;
}

myAddB('hello', ' ', 'world');
```

gives me " hello world"

or why

```
function myAddC(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z;
}

myAddC('hello' + ' ' + 'world');
```

Gives me "hello worldundefinedundefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because y and z are `undefined`...

You only pass one `String`. `x` will have something but `y` and `z` will be `undefined`:

```
myAdd('hello' + ' ' + 'world');

'hello' + ' ' + 'world' -> is all concatenated into 1 String...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you are only passing one argument to `myAdd` -- `'hello' + ' ' + 'world'`